# Get the value from a present in the li

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
  var item1 = $( "li > a[data-itemid='"+v+"']" );
  console.log(item1);
  var va= $(this).find(item1).attr('value');
```

**My li**

```
<li relatemodule="Users" name="assigned_user_id" data-itemid="1" class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#" data-itemid="1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Administrator</a></li>
```

What i am trying to find the a present in the particular li of the ul and then extract the value from a

Been trying this for a while but i get an undefined in the `va`

I need to extract the value **Administrator**

```
<ul id="user_id1_c" name="user_id1_c" data-role="listview" relate="yes" relatedmodule="Users" linkedmodule="" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search items..." class="ui-listview"><li relatemodule="Users" name="user_id1_c" data-itemid="1" class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#" data-itemid="1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Administrator</a></li><ul>
```

Please help

**EDIT:**

The item1 values i get as in the picture but i am getting va as blank

```
  var item1 = $("li > a[data-itemid='" + v + "']");
  console.log(item1);
  var va = $(this).find(item1).text();
```

[image]

**Here is my whole code:**

```
$("#editcasedata").find('input, select, textarea,ul,li').each(function () {
//console.log($(this).attr('name'));
if ($(this).val() === 'Submit') {} else {

    var input = $(this);

    //console.log(input);

    $.each(data, function () {

        $.each(this, function (k, v) {


            if (input.attr('name') === k) {
                if (input.attr('type') === 'checkbox') {

                    if (v == 1) {
                        $(input).prop('checked', true);

                    } else {
                        $(input).prop('checked', false);
                    }
                }
                if (input.attr('type') === 'multienum') {
                    var values = v.substring(1, v.length - 1);

                    $.each(values.split("^,^"), function (i, e) {

                        if (e !== '') {
                            $(input).find("option[value=" + e + "]").prop("selected", true);


                            //$(input).find("option[value=" + e + "]").prop("aria-selected",true);
                        }
                    });


                } else if (input.attr('type') === 'datetime-local') {

                    if (v) {

                        var $valdate = serverToLocalJsDateObj(v);


                        if (!isNaN($valdate.getTime())) {
                            $valdate = $valdate.toISOString();
                            console.log($valdate);
                            $valdate = $valdate.split('Z')[0];
                            console.log($valdate, v);

                            $(input).val($valdate);
                        }
                    }


                } else if (input.attr('relate') === 'yes') {



                    var item1 = $("li > a[data-itemid='" + v + "']");
                    console.log(item1);
                    var va = $(this).find(item1).text();

                    console.log(va);
                    $('[check="yes"]', e.target).attr('type', 'text');
                    $('[check="yes"]', e.target).attr('main', v);
                    $('[check="yes"]', e.target).val(va);

                } else {


                    $(input).val(v);

                    //'#'+$(input).attr('name').val(v);
                }

                $("#editcasedata").append(input.html()).trigger('create');
            }

        });






    });



}


});
```

Comment: Done sorry was in a hurry

Comment: What do you mean the `value`? you want the `href` out of the anchor tag? or what? There is no value="" in your `a` tag

Comment: i need to extract the value Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text()` function to get the value of the `a` tag:

```
var item1 = $( "li > a[data-itemid='"+v+"']" );
var va = $(this).find(item1).text();
console.log(va);
```

`.attr('value')` will look for the `value=""` attribute that is why you are getting `undefined`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P59BD/1/)**

Comment: i get blank values for both don't know maybe there is some issue with my ul

Comment: In my fiddle it is working fine because I changed `$( "li > a[data-itemid='"+v+"']" );` to `$( "li > a[data-itemid='1']" );` You need to double check your declaration of `v`. Otherwise please post a fiddle of your complete post here in the comments

Comment: Doesn't show the li as well now i have put in my entire code kindly check

Comment: Try `var va = $(this).find(item1).attr('href');console.log(va);` see if you get the `href` attribute value... if not then it is not finding `li > a[data-itemid='"+v+"']` inside `#editcasedata`

Comment: i get an undefined though it is defined

Comment: If you can make a fiddle with your HTML, I will test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58562/discussion-between-vini-and-imbondbaby).

Answer (score 0):

[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function is what you need:

```
var item1 = $( "li > a[data-itemid='"+v+"']" );
console.log(item1);
var va= $(this).find(item1).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the `item1`, there is no need to `find()` it

Just `var va = item1.text()` will do